# Cardinality of the set of all monoids with countably many elements

Tags: set-theory

How can I prove assuming the continuum hypothesis, that the cardinality of the set of all monoids with countably many elements has cardinality the same as that of the power set of the real numbers.

Thanks.

Comment: Where is the continuum hypothesis going to be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are these monoids on a fixed countable set? If so, then I don't think this is correct. A monoid is determined by $\cdot : A \times A \to A$. It isn't hard to see that the collection of all monoid operators has an inclusion into the full set of functions $A \times A \to A$. This set has cardinality

$$|A \times A|^{|A|} = (\aleph_0 \cdot \aleph_0)^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_0^{\aleph_0} = \beth_1 = |\mathbb{R}|.$$

Here I've only used at most countable choice. So on a fixed set $A$ the cardinality in question is at most $\beth_1$.

Comment: The set they are on isn't fixed, but also isn't arbitrary. Any countable subset of the reals.

Comment: @rumdog Then you end up with essentially $|B| \cdot \left ( \aleph_0 \right )^{\aleph_0}$, where $|B|$ is the cardinality of the set of countable subsets of the real numbers. Given choice this is $\max \{ |B|,\beth_1 \}$, which is necessarily just $|B|$ (since $|B| \geq |\mathbb{R}|$ of course). I'm not entirely sure what $|B|$ is (I am not a set theorist), though I suspect it is actually $\beth_1$, not $\beth_2$.

Comment: Thanks for your help, maybe the question has a mistake?

Comment: The cardinality of the set of countably infinite subsets of the reals is at most the cardinality of $\mathbb{R^N}$, right? Which is the cardinality of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Thanks, I think you guys are right.